# Simple object hierarchy with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to make hierarhical mapping Hibernate?

For example:
Category

```
id parent_id name
1  0         Root
2  1         Sub-root 1
3  1         Sub-root 2
4  2         Sub-(sub-root 1)
```

Is it possible to make lazy mapping for such `Category` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you are asking.

However it would appear you are talking about a self-referencing relationship rather than Inheritance so you can then map as below. The default fetch strategy should be same as for any other `@OneToMany` i.e. LAZY.

```
@Entity
public class Category{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Category> subCategories;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to ask about inheritance of entities. I recommend using JPA inheritance strategies. There are 3 available.

1. [Single Table](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/14/jpa-single-table-inheritance-example/): Uses only one database table. columns need to be nullable and hence wastes database space
2. [Joined Strategy](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/17/jpa-joined-inheritance-example/): Uses multiple table which can be joined for insertion and retrieval of entity data. Saves database space but performance becomes an issue when inheritance hierarchy becomes wide and deep
3. [Table per concrete class](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/17/jpa-table-per-concrete-class-example/): Uses separate database tables which are not joined.

Different strategies have different advantages and disadvantages. You can choose according to your need.